# How can I fix "An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed"?

Tags: javascript, html

JS error :

> An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 beginAnchor("javascript:popupManager.close()");
</script>
<img src="../images/icons/icon_cancel.gif" border="0" alt="" title="">

<script type="text/javascript">
 endAnchor();
</script>
```

Comment: Apparently this is what happens in some browsers, when you open an html tag in one `<script>` block, and close it in another

Comment: any solutuion to this

Comment: What you are trying to achieve

Comment: i want to remove that js error. so how can i structure my code to do the same

Comment: "This is not an off-topic question!!! It's a known Firefox warning. See the replies this question received. 
In fact, the specific script code is of no importance here. It happens with any script!

The person or persons who closed this thread as off-topic *should not be allowed to close threads* since they cannot understand what is and what is not off-topic."

Comment: @Apostolos I've tried to get this question reopened a few times now, I think. Just voted again to reopen it.

Comment: I don't quite understand, @Stijn. Do you mean the question cannot be reopened even if you upvoted it? I upvoted it too, yesterday. How many upvotes are needed to "resurrect" this question?  Yet, I see that the thread is still alive, since here we are commenting about it! :))

Comment: @Apostolos It needs 5 reopen votes, upvotes are unrelated to the question being reopened. It's currently at 2 reopen votes. If the question isn't reopened within a certain time window (a certain number of days I think), the reopen votes expire.

Comment: I see, @Stijn. Upvoting is not enough. But then how can the question be reopened? I don't see any link provided for that purpose! Nor can I see any "reopen votes" anywhere. Where do you see all this 'reopen" stuff and how did you try to reopen the question? 
Should we maybe reword the question? E.g. "What is an 'unbalanced tree' in javascript and what does produce it?  (Example of code is not necessary since the problem can occur in any -- more or less large -- script.
I woulld suggest that you do that since you know better ...

Comment: @Apostolos you need 3000 reputation for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges for details. Editing the question might help, yes.

Comment: Aha. Maybe in 10 years, then! :))

Answer (score 5):

It's not an error, it's a warning. It happens in Firefox 4 and later.

From [MDN: Optimizing your pages for speculative parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Optimizing_your_pages_for_speculative_parsing):

> However, in Firefox 4 and later the HTML parser also runs the HTML tree construction algorithm speculatively. The upside is that when a speculation succeeds, there's no need to reparse the part of the incoming file that was already scanned for scripts, style sheets and images. The downside is that there's more work lost when the speculation fails.
>   [...]
>   Speculative tree building fails when `document.write()` changes the tree builder state such that the speculative state after the `</script>` tag no longer holds when all the content inserted by `document.write()` has been parsed. However, only unusual uses of `document.write()` cause trouble. Here are the things to avoid:
>   [...]
>   **Don't write unbalanced trees. `<script>document.write("<div>");</script>` is bad. `<script>document.write("<div></div>");</script>` is OK.**

The solution is to write the HTML in a single `<script>` block, if you care about the performance loss. You can also ignore it if you want to.

Comment: I get this warning with `document.write()` when I'm not even writing HTML tags (I'm just writing plain text without tags). I'm guessing one key to avoiding this is to call `document.write()` within the HTML body, rather than above in the script tags. Maybe it's writing the text before the body tag. Here's an example that causes the warning to be given: https://pastebin.com/qp1Sh4me

Comment: Up there, I meant 'rather than above in the script tags in the heading tags'. I tried it out in the body. Yep, putting the script tags containing `document.write()` within the body removes the warning: e.g. https://pastebin.com/r3KJ0cWS

Comment: This is definitely a false alarm, if not a bug, since it occurs even if one doesn't use 'document.write()'. So maybe, it's a proprietary (Moziilla) bug and the issue should be addressed to Bugzilla ...
But before that, and since it has been brought up in here, I would really like to know what makes a script "unbalanced" (If there's such a thing at all)

Comment: I had a similar issue, this helped me to understand and fix it. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     beginAnchor("javascript:popupManager.close()");
     response.write('<img src="../images/icons/icon_cancel.gif" border="0" alt="">');
     endAnchor();

  </script>
```

This wil probably solve it, but it's not the kind of code that I would recommend.